# Animation Montage does not play as correctly with blended animation

Tags: animation, unreal-engine4, blending, blueprint

I upload a same question at Answerhub as well but i can't take the answer of it. Here is the link : [Animation Montage does not play as correctly with blended animation](https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/1031221/view.html)

I have problems about animation blending. When i play animation montage, It is play well but has bad blending quality. I want to play animation montage below

[image: image1]

But Actual animation is played like below
[image: image2]

Arm moving just a little with at that same time the debug line is drawn. I want to play animation montage at first image. How can i solve this? I think it should be override animation montage slot then animation in game can play well but i don't know what and how should i do.

this is a animation blueprint.
[image: image3]

Bone blending option is

```
Bone Name = spine_01
Blend Depth = 0

Mesh Space Rotation Blend = true
Mesh Space Scale Blend = false
Curve Blend Option = Override
Blend Root Motion Based on Root Bone = true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer my self.

1. Open your animation montage
2. Checkout `Asset Details - Blend Option`
3. Change `Blend In/Blend Time` value. In my case, my problems are solved after i set it `0.0`

I think the animation using at animation montage is very short so it is finished before `Blend In`

Answer (score 0):

need more information.
show which bones are blended in two '본마다 레이어로 블렌딩합니다' nodes

i think first of them (left node) should be your left arm bone.
and second one should be upper body.

Comment: Okay, I've modified my Animation graph and added blending options!

Comment: There is 'Always Update Source Pose' Option in 'WeaponAttack' Slot Node Setting,
is this option checked?

Comment: It is unchecked.